# A simple riddle on a common word

Tags: riddle

I can ruin the fun or make it dirty

I start with a hybrid form at atomic level

Something responsible for wars is right in the middle of me

If there is an emergency, you reach at my end

You can try to hide your answer, but I shall reveal myself anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the appropriate answer is:

> **SPOILER**

*I can ruin the fun or make it dirty*

> A **spoiler** can 'ruin the fun' (like in giving away a movie twist) or 'make (something) dirty' by spoiling or ruining it.

*I start with a hybrid form at atomic level*

> '**SP** hybridisation' is where the s orbital of an atom overlaps with one p orbital.

*Something responsible for wars is right in the middle of me*

> Many wars have been fought over **OIL**.

*If there is an emergency, you reach at my end*

> In a medical emergency you may end up in the Emergency Room, or **ER**.

*You can try to hide your answer, but I shall reveal myself anyway*

> As is customary on PSE I have hidden my answer using a **spoiler tag** (>!) but it has still been revealed nonetheless!

Comment: Mods, note: I am aware that at least one [other riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24847/i-can-ruin-a-party) on this site has the same answer, but a search of the archive hasn't turned up a question with the same way of deriving it, hence why I have answered it. It is a very difficult word to search for and find relevant results! :)

Comment: Two more - [Puzzlingly meta… what the heck can it be?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10568/puzzlingly-meta-what-the-heck-can-it-be) & [Gdansk Knight to you](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31021/gdansk-knight-to-you) - but varied clues.

Comment: @Tom It's definitely a popular choice! We had another one semi-recently I recall where the answer was rot13(gur fcbvyre gnt) but for obvious reasons I'm struggling to find it!

Comment: Thanks @Stiv for pointing it out. I just randomly thought of this and was almost sure someone else might have thought of it before me. Like you said, I did the word search and could not find the puzzle anywhere. This is my first post, so wanted to try anyway

Comment: @PagMax It's a definitely a word close to the hearts and minds of regular PSE users! The main difficulty with the search box is that words in spoiler tags do not show in search results - so you often have to search for other words used in the riddle and hope for the best... It's a very inexact art :) Anyway, well done for having a crack at it, and welcome to the community!